# Extjs 4.1 disable panel preview when collapsed

Tags: extjs, header, panel, preview

Let's suppose that we have the following code:

```
Ext.create ( 'Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout : 'border',
    items  : [{
        region : 'west',
        xtype  : 'panel',
        collapsible : true,
        id     : 'panel1_id',
        width  : '45%'
    }, {
        region    : 'center',
        xtype     : 'panel',
        id        : 'panel2_id',
        width     : '55%'
    }]
});
```

As we can see, the first panel is collapsible. My question is: 
is it possible to disable the panel's preview (when we click on the collapsed panel's header) when collapsed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not collapased. You need to set `collapsed: true` for that.

```
Ext.create ( 'Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout : 'border',
        items  : [{
                    region : 'west',
                    xtype  : 'panel',
                    collapsible : true, // this show the tool within the header
                    collapsed: true, // this collapses 
                    floatable: false, // prevent floating on header-click when collapsed
                    id     : 'panel1_id',
                    width  : '45%'
                  },{
                    region    : 'center',
                    xtype     : 'panel',
                    id        : 'panel2_id',
                    width     : '55%'
                  }]
});
```

Comment: Ok, but when you click on the header (not on the collapse/expand button) when the panel is collapsed, there is an event that displays the panel's content like a preview and that's what I want to disable.

Comment: @Marthym_biz For that define the panel with `floatable: false`. That will prevent it. See my edit

Comment: I'm new to extjs that's why I was looking for a config like enablePreview or something like that. I should've read the doc more attentively.
Thanks

Comment: @Marthym_biz I guess this wan't the last time ;) Thew API is quite huge. Most time it helps to look at all events that get fired from any specific instance. You can do this with `Ext.util.Observable.capture(Ext.getCmp('id'),function(){console.log(arguments)})`

Comment: i need floatable set false, and Also How to expand with header click like button click?